# Do both of the saves against a Heightened Phantasmal Force receive disadvantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If Phantasmal Force is Heightened, does the target receive a penalty on both its initial Int Save **and** the subsequent Investigation check?

Comment: I edited your title to match what I think your question is; feel free to edit or revert if I didn't get it right.

Comment: Perhaps edit it to accurately reflect that there's only one save. The second "save" as labelled here is actually an ability check that must use the character/creatures action.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Heightened Spell gives disadvantage on the *first* **saving throw** a creature makes to resist the spell's effect. An ability check is **not** a saving throw and even it it were, subsequent checks would no longer be the *first* the creatures makes to resist the spell's effects.

Comment: Thank you! I'm probably not going to get that Metamagic.